# PromQL statement does not work whilst the same Recording Rule does

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have these two recording rules, which work:

```
  - record: job:sum_rate
    expr: sum(rate(promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total[5m]))
  - record: job:sum_rate:avg_over_time
    expr: avg_over_time(job:sum_rate[10m])
```

When I try to enter the same expression into Prometheus directly though (e.g. in Grafana), meaning I enter `avg_over_time(sum(rate(promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total[5m]))[10m])`, Prometheus tells me:

`Error executing query: invalid parameter "query": 1:68: parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors`

Why is that? Where is my misunderstanding? For testing purposes, I'd like to enter the given expression directly without a recording rule, since I need data of the last three weeks and a recording rule would start collecting data from scratch, though the data has already been monitored.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by trial and error. To my understanding, a recording rule saves the data as a range vector, which avg_over_time() and rate() need as data type. The statements I entered in Grafana yield instant vectors though, so there is a mismatch. Entering avg_over_time(sum(rate(promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total[5m:15s]))[10m:15s]) solved the problem, because now these are range vectors